# Build error in Geany

Tags: build, raspberry-pi, geany, wiringpi

I am working on a project using a Raspberry Pi 3, I am trying to control NeoPixel leds and a lcd display with it so I used rpi_281x and wiringPi libraries to do it. My issue is that I dont know how to add the rpi_281x library to the builder of Geany, I did add wiringPi library by writting -lwiringPi but that didnt work for the other library, even using the full path, it keeps saying that it could not be found. THe rpi_281x library came with an scons builder so I dont know if it has something to do with my issue. Here are the links to both libraries.

rpi_281x: https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x

WiringPi: https://git.drogon.net/?p=wiringPi;a=summary

I would appreciate any suggestion for an alternative method to build this as detailed  as possible. The issue is not with WiringPi, basically I need help with adding the rpi_281x to Geany-s builder. The code does get compiled, but not built.

Thanks